# Emacs daemon is automatically killed when I close gui client in fullscreen mode. (Mac Yosemite)

Tags: user-interface, emacs, fullscreen, daemon, kill

Here's my .zshrc configuration.

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
alias e="emacsclient -t"      # emacs terminal
alias ec="emacsclient -c -n"  # gui emacsclient
```

When I start a new first emacsclient, emacs daemon starts automatically with the configuration above.
But, I got a trouble with gui emacs.

This is a starting message of a first emacsclient.

```
╭─dplee@dpleeui-MacBook-Pro  ~  
╰─$ ec .zshrc
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
ad-handle-definition: `evil-mode' got redefined
[yas] Discovered there was already *scratch* in fundamental-mode
[yas] Discovered there was already  *code-conversion-work* in fundamental-mode
[yas] Discovered there was already  *load* in fundamental-mode
[yas] Loading for `fundamental-mode', just-in-time: (lambda nil (yas--load-directory-1 (quote /Users/dplee/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20150811.1222/snippets/fundamental-mode) (quote fundamental-mode)))!
[yas] Loading compiled snippets from /Users/dplee/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20150811.1222/snippets/fundamental-mode
Loading /Users/dplee/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20150811.1222/snippets/fundamental-mode/.yas-setup...
Loading /Users/dplee/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20150811.1222/snippets/fundamental-mode/.yas-setup...done
[yas] Prepared just-in-time loading for /Users/dplee/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20150811.1222/snippets
[yas] Check your `yas-snippet-dirs': ~/.emacs.d/snippets is not a directory
[yas] Reloaded everything (snippets will load just-in-time)... (some errors, check *Messages*).
[yas] Check your `yas-snippet-dirs': ~/.emacs.d/remote-snippets is not a directory
[yas] Check your `yas-snippet-dirs': ~/.emacs.d/snippets is not a directory
[yas] Reloaded everything (snippets will load just-in-time)... (some errors, check *Messages*).
ad-handle-definition: `tramp-read-passwd' got redefined
Starting Emacs daemon.
Emacs daemon should have started, trying to connect again
```

Now emacs daemon is started well.

```
╭─dplee@dpleeui-MacBook-Pro  ~  
╰─$ ps -ef | grep emacs
  501 12057     1   0  7:15AM ??         0:01.95 /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw --daemon=^J4,5^J
  501 12139 10891   0  7:16AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn emacs
```

But, if I close the gui client which is in state of full-screen window mode, the emacs daemon is also killed. (I can't see any emacs daemon process in the ps result.)
It doesn't happen when the client window isn't in full-screen.

Here's a detailed error message and stack frame when the problem occurred.
Anybody who already encountered this situation?

```
Process:               Emacs [12057]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
Identifier:            org.gnu.Emacs
Version:               Version 24.5 (9.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Terminal [7109]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-08-21 07:20:51.883 +0900
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        9F7B494C-3D13-B1A9-822B-480554ACE9A0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       978C9798-989F-49BD-8CDE-E684910CBC6F

Time Awake Since Boot: 8100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018

VM Regions Near 0x18:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-00000001001d2000 [ 1864K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c781c82 __kill + 10
1   org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000bae91 emacs_abort + 19
2   org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100173933 ns_term_shutdown + 124
3   org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000a1c1b shut_down_emacs + 283
4   org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000a19f5 terminate_due_to_signal + 89
5   org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000bccf1 handle_fatal_signal + 14
6   org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000bc18d deliver_fatal_thread_signal + 114
7   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff83394f1a _sigtramp + 26
8   ???                             0x00000001011632b0 0 + 4313199280
9   org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100186a15 update_frame_tool_bar + 374
10  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100178b30 -[EmacsView windowDidExitFullScreen:] + 117
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8433845c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84228634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b7659d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85bdfd68 __18-[NSWindow _close]_block_invoke + 650
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85bdfa96 -[NSWindow _close] + 376
16  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100170401 x_free_frame_resources + 301
17  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x000000010017043c x_destroy_window + 22
18  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x000000010000fa83 delete_frame + 1060
19  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x000000010011165d Ffuncall + 764
20  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100144091 exec_byte_code + 2064
21  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001001115b4 Ffuncall + 595
22  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100144091 exec_byte_code + 2064
23  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001001115b4 Ffuncall + 595
24  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x000000010010cf4f Fcall_interactively + 4951
25  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x000000010011174b Ffuncall + 1002
26  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100144091 exec_byte_code + 2064
27  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001001115b4 Ffuncall + 595
28  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x0000000100111be4 call1 + 45
29  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000a52c1 command_loop_1 + 2807
30  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x000000010011008f internal_condition_case + 251
31  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000b3dd8 command_loop_2 + 53
32  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x000000010010fab9 internal_catch + 243
33  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000a3fbb recursive_edit_1 + 211
34  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000a415e Frecursive_edit + 236
35  org.gnu.Emacs                   0x00000001000a3128 main + 5300
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff86e195c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c783232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8c351a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c7823fa __select + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8b79cdc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b4268 _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b41e5 _pthread_start + 176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b241d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c77d4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c77c64f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8428aeb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8428a37b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84289bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85a8756b _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b4268 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b41e5 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b241d thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c78294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff845b240d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbfe398  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000002f19  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfe3c0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfe398
   r8: 0x000000000000007f   r9: 0x000000010112a9b0  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00000001005008e0  r13: 0x0000000100500880  r14: 0x0000000000000028  r15: 0x0000000000000020
  rip: 0x00007fff8c781c82  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000153c26000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000025
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x1001d1fef +org.gnu.Emacs (Version 24.5 - 9.0) <483F1878-6D65-3857-B6FD-B8AF26448D51> /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
       0x100607000 -        0x100629fff  libKoreanConverter.dylib (64) <E51FCBAE-3886-32B7-B4F8-51B3CBF683ED> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libKoreanConverter.dylib
       0x101396000 -        0x101396ffe +cl_kernels (???) <012559FA-4256-401A-81B6-A07DD27C2241> cl_kernels
       0x10139a000 -        0x10139afef +cl_kernels (???) <38644E76-CFB8-4AEC-956A-4250D9C79DBB> cl_kernels
       0x1014fe000 -        0x1014feff5 +cl_kernels (???) <89679EEA-76F0-40A9-A5CA-1FF5D05AE998> cl_kernels
       0x1051fd000 -        0x1051fdfef +cl_kernels (???) <38644E76-CFB8-4AEC-956A-4250D9C79DBB> cl_kernels
       0x10af22000 -        0x10b008fef  unorm8_bgra.dylib (2.4.5) <5F488C7E-2FB2-3C66-9764-28CF16B03E7A> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_bgra.dylib
       0x10b6dc000 -        0x10b6dcfe7 +cl_kernels (???) <A4AD5F3E-1691-4D0C-BBED-6EBD22C053D8> cl_kernels
    0x7fff6c71f000 -     0x7fff6c755837  dyld (353.2.1) <72A99D0F-0B56-3938-ABC5-67A0F33757C4> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff82fde000 -     0x7fff82fe8ff7  com.apple.NetAuth (5.2 - 5.2) <2BBD749A-8E18-35B8-8E48-A90347C1CCA7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff83003000 -     0x7fff83006fff  libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib (788.2) <CE4BA36F-F61E-39E8-95A8-91891E794ED6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib
    0x7fff8304e000 -     0x7fff83059ff7  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.10 - 631) <C44259AC-0A1C-3EC5-99AC-48CB520A709D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
    0x7fff8305a000 -     0x7fff83341ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1108.6 - 1108.6) <8953580E-7857-33B2-AA64-98296830D3A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff83384000 -     0x7fff8338ffff  libGL.dylib (11.1.2) <FD8B7B67-1532-32A1-B369-9D7A6C1EB3ED> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff83390000 -     0x7fff83398fff  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <64E34079-D712-3D66-9CE2-418624A5C040> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff833a8000 -     0x7fff833b0fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (576.30.4) <4EA2DEC3-77EE-3941-A703-DE6DC2056B15> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff833b1000 -     0x7fff83495fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (52.30.1) <093A3CCE-953A-365F-9412-775DE0AF2870> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff83496000 -     0x7fff834acff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <F153AC5B-0542-356E-88C8-20A62CA704E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff834ad000 -     0x7fff834f9ff7  libcups.2.dylib (408.2) <E8AD18F9-61E4-3791-B840-504468C25556> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff836c9000 -     0x7fff836ccffb  libCGXType.A.dylib (788.2) <2F4BD0F4-9A86-3611-9004-F14E4FDCBAE9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
    0x7fff836cd000 -     0x7fff83721fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff83722000 -     0x7fff83816fff  libFontParser.dylib (134.4) <12F2E476-F05A-3F01-92FF-6E0C6D7F8DD5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff83817000 -     0x7fff83842fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 229) <F03DFAC6-6285-3176-9C6D-7CC50F8CD52A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff8419f000 -     0x7fff84217ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14.4 - 1.14) <E3495342-E80D-358D-9290-6C02F5F46BCA> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff84218000 -     0x7fff845b0ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1153.18) <5C0892B8-9691-341F-9279-CA3A74D59AA0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff845b1000 -     0x7fff845bafff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.10.1) <3103AA7F-3BAE-3673-9649-47FFD7E15C97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff845bb000 -     0x7fff845d7ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.30.1) <DDA8928B-CC0D-3255-BD8A-3FEA0982B890> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff84646000 -     0x7fff84660ff7  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1) <7760E0C2-A222-3709-B2A6-B692D900CEB1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff84661000 -     0x7fff84685ff7  com.apple.Sharing (328.17 - 328.17) <AD5E243A-B79F-3D7B-800B-A2C99A1CFEF1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework/Versions/A/Sharing
    0x7fff84686000 -     0x7fff8468eff3  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1210.20.1 - 1210.20.1) <84F79D3E-7B5E-3C93-8479-35794A3F125E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff8469a000 -     0x7fff849b5fcf  com.apple.vImage (8.0 - 8.0) <1183FE6A-FDB6-3B3B-928D-50C7909F2308> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff84ab7000 -     0x7fff84b4cff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.9.0 - 4.9.0) <9150C2B7-2E6E-3509-96EA-7B3F959F049E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff84b4d000 -     0x7fff84b4effb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff84b51000 -     0x7fff84b56fff  libsystem_stats.dylib (163.30.2) <48A9387D-5C63-3E79-979C-F675552F6FC9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff84b57000 -     0x7fff84b62ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (5.3.3 - 5.3.3) <A5640275-E2A6-3856-95EF-5F0DC440B10C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff84b63000 -     0x7fff84b83ff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework (264.6 - 264.6) <B4BDB2C0-5D4E-30F4-8EB0-CC16C91DF418> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff84b84000 -     0x7fff84bbbffb  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5) <CAFB9695-000F-34EA-8DF5-09996929C26A> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
    0x7fff84e27000 -     0x7fff84e2dfff  libsystem_trace.dylib (72.20.1) <840F5301-B55A-3078-90B9-FEFFD6CD741A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff84e2e000 -     0x7fff84e2efff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.12 - 1.12) <E5335492-7EFE-31EA-BE72-4A9CEE68D58E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff84e2f000 -     0x7fff84e53fef  libJPEG.dylib (1238) <8CB4D185-069F-38FE-ABB9-25E514DE227D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff84e5d000 -     0x7fff84e8afff  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 145.1) <18DB07E0-B927-3260-A234-636F298D1917> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff84e8b000 -     0x7fff84e8ffff  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <CCA42EE2-3400-3444-9486-BC454E60D944> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
    0x7fff84e90000 -     0x7fff84e92fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.30.1) <B124CC64-59B9-354F-A693-B3431ADB87AC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff84e9c000 -     0x7fff84ee9ff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (10.3 - 451.1) <DE992474-0841-38A1-B4F6-46D653E454D5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff84eeb000 -     0x7fff85013ff7  com.apple.coreui (2.1 - 308.6) <9E0E9C6A-68F5-34C1-A17C-96226D401D4D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff85014000 -     0x7fff8503bfff  com.apple.shortcut (2.14 - 2.14) <0E9228EC-E688-3E83-9516-5211FFEA923E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Shortcut.framework/Versions/A/Shortcut
    0x7fff850ba000 -     0x7fff8512effb  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55126) <D3C26373-83B1-3FDF-AD9C-39875D84312A> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff85179000 -     0x7fff851f2fe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.30.1) <5779FFA0-4D9A-3AD4-B7F2-618227621DC8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff851f3000 -     0x7fff8520eff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (34) <D64842BE-7BD4-3D0C-9842-1D202F7C2A51> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff8520f000 -     0x7fff85215fff  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (5.0.9 - 5.0.9) <BB2D573F-0A01-379F-A2BA-3C454EDCB111> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff8524c000 -     0x7fff85252ff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.30.1) <3E99FF35-DCBB-3A4C-8853-F1F39A792D29> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff85253000 -     0x7fff85279fff  com.apple.ChunkingLibrary (2.1 - 163.6) <29D4CB95-42EF-34C6-8182-BDB6F7BB1E79> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/Versions/A/ChunkingLibrary
    0x7fff8527a000 -     0x7fff852adfff  com.apple.MediaKit (16 - 757.2) <2912E5C2-085F-3FE2-8531-23B6E894B0F0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaKit.framework/Versions/A/MediaKit
    0x7fff852ae000 -     0x7fff852fffff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0) <450293F7-DAE7-3DD0-8F7C-71FC2FD72627> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff85303000 -     0x7fff8530eff7  libkxld.dylib (2782.30.5) <14CB6513-E373-3829-AD7D-F1C15397F64F> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff8530f000 -     0x7fff8531aff7  libcsfde.dylib (471.30.1) <A62AE3D8-E2A6-314A-BF45-804003BE0AC9> /usr/lib/libcsfde.dylib
    0x7fff8531b000 -     0x7fff8544bfff  com.apple.UIFoundation (1.0 - 1) <466BDFA8-0B9F-3AB0-989D-F9779422926A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/Versions/A/UIFoundation
    0x7fff855a3000 -     0x7fff855b5ff7  com.apple.CoreDuetDaemonProtocol (1.0 - 1) <CE9FABB4-1C5D-3F9B-9BB8-5CC50C3E5E31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/Versions/A/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
    0x7fff855b6000 -     0x7fff855b7fff  liblangid.dylib (117) <B54A4AA0-2E53-3671-90F5-AFF711C0EB9E> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
... (omit)
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
        0x7fff9150c000 -     0x7fff915e2ff3  com.apple.DiskImagesFramework (10.10.4 - 397) <8B513846-28A2-3275-B8A0-DF08C5EC077A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Versions/A/DiskImages
        0x7fff918ce000 -     0x7fff918cffff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
        0x7fff918d0000 -     0x7fff918d3fff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <D94F7F86-4015-3453-92FD-ADC04F215C04> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
        0x7fff918d4000 -     0x7fff91ae1ffb  com.apple.CFNetwork (720.4.4 - 720.4.4) <71A596B3-A837-3ADF-9560-1DCDA9292F96> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
        0x7fff91b05000 -     0x7fff91b45ff7  libGLImage.dylib (11.1.2) <9B05F3BF-D111-3B01-B7F8-C5EF7E02000B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
        0x7fff91c8c000 -     0x7fff91d2efff  com.apple.Bluetooth (4.3.5 - 4.3.5f8) <DB1CF332-A131-3DF1-BE85-A05594F6DA5F> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth
        0x7fff91db3000 -     0x7fff91e25fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1050.20.2) <09C0518C-90DF-3FC3-96D6-34D35F72C8EF> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
        0x7fff91e26000 -     0x7fff91e27ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <9615D10A-FCA7-3BE4-AA1A-1B195DACE1A1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
        0x7fff91e28000 -     0x7fff91e82ff7  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 1) <ACA93FE0-A0E3-333E-AE3C-8EB7DE5F362F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
        0x7fff91e93000 -     0x7fff91e95fff  libquarantine.dylib (76.20.1) <7AF90041-2768-378A-925A-D83161863642> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
        0x7fff91e96000 -     0x7fff91ec6ff7  libncurses.5.4.dylib (44) <F09809A4-53B9-3E91-A8FA-D3F584C03AA3> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
        0x7fff91edf000 -     0x7fff92046ffb  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.12 - 1.12) <5678FC94-456A-3F5F-BA9A-10EB6E462997> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
        0x7fff9252d000 -     0x7fff92555fff  libRIP.A.dylib (788.2) <4DAA8224-AD10-3865-BF9F-DF56168914F9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
        0x7fff92556000 -     0x7fff92556fff  com.apple.CoreServices (62 - 62) <C69DA8A7-B536-34BF-A93F-1C170E2C6D58> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
        0x7fff92557000 -     0x7fff92564ff3  com.apple.ProtocolBuffer (1 - 228.0.1) <3429EB06-9F0E-355F-B9AB-F72879177398> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/Versions/A/ProtocolBuffer
        0x7fff92565000 -     0x7fff925d1fff  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (5.0 - 500.35.2) <03697149-1CDD-32FF-B564-1C1EF5E9E5C3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
        0x7fff925d2000 -     0x7fff925d5fff  com.apple.IOSurface (97.4 - 97.4) <AE11CFBC-4D46-30F3-BEEC-4C8131079391> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
        0x7fff925d6000 -     0x7fff92691ff7  com.apple.DiscRecording (9.0 - 9000.4.2) <4655B4B8-523D-3AE6-92A0-8486A2258B3B> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecording
        0x7fff92692000 -     0x7fff92911ffb  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle (6.06 - 819) <EDA3D142-24EC-3661-87EB-B35F8E858A9D> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
        0x7fff92912000 -     0x7fff929a6fff  com.apple.ink.framework (10.9 - 213) <8E029630-1530-3734-A446-13353F0E7AC5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
        0x7fff92a29000 -     0x7fff92a63ffb  com.apple.DebugSymbols (115 - 115) <6F03761D-7C3A-3C80-8031-AA1C1AD7C706> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols
        0x7fff92a64000 -     0x7fff92a6cff7  com.apple.icloud.FindMyDevice (1.0 - 1) <9CE67F85-2BA8-3093-97BA-07BF5C04A5D6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FindMyDevice.framework/Versions/A/FindMyDevice
        0x7fff92a6d000 -     0x7fff92a80ff7  com.apple.CoreBluetooth (1.0 - 1) <8D7BA9BA-EB36-307A-9119-0B3D9732C953> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
        0x7fff92a81000 -     0x7fff92ab3ff3  com.apple.frameworks.CoreDaemon (1.3 - 1.3) <C6DB0A07-F8E4-3837-BCA9-225F460EDA81> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDaemon.framework/Versions/B/CoreDaemon
        0x7fff92ab4000 -     0x7fff92ae4fff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib

    External Modification Summary:
      Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
        task_for_pid: 68
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by this process:
        task_for_pid: 0
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by all processes on this machine:
        task_for_pid: 291025
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0

    VM Region Summary:
    ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=187.9M resident=78.6M(42%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=109.3M(58%)
    Writable regions: Total=198.5M written=51.5M(26%) resident=85.8M(43%) swapped_out=4K(0%) unallocated=112.7M(57%)

    REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
    ===========                      =======
    Activity Tracing                   2048K
    CG backing stores                  20.7M
    CG image                            532K
    CG raster data                     27.0M
    CG shared images                    368K
    CoreAnimation                        48K
    CoreGraphics                         12K
    CoreImage                            28K
    CoreUI image data                   232K
    Dispatch continuations             16.0M
    Foundation                            4K
    Kernel Alloc Once                     8K
    MALLOC                             79.4M
    MALLOC (admin)                       32K
    Memory Tag 242                       12K
    OpenCL                               40K
    STACK GUARD                        55.7M
    Stack                              13.5M
    Stack (reserved)                    520K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
    VM_ALLOCATE                        17.2M
    __DATA                             46.6M
    __IMAGE                             528K
    __LINKEDIT                         71.4M
    __TEXT                            116.4M
    __UNICODE                           552K
    mapped file                       121.8M
    shared memory                         4K
    ===========                      =======
    TOTAL                             590.6M
    TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    590.1M


    Model: MacBookPro11,4, BootROM MBP114.0172.B04, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.29f24
    Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
    Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
    Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x152), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
    Bluetooth: Version 4.3.5f8 15969, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
    Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
    USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
    USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
    Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: > emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible that this is emacs bug.
So I reported this problem to emacs maintainer.

Comment: I've had this problem as well.  I think this is the same: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2015-11/msg00020.html